# r data.frame create a conditional column

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have data as below. I want a new column called `accuracy_level`. How can I get it done? I tried `if` but it didn't work well.

If the

- `accuracy_percentage` is within +/-10% then `accuracy_level` will be "Good"
- `accuracy_percentage` is within +/-30% and outside +/- 10% then `accuracy_level` will be "Bad"
- `accuracy_percentage` is outside +/-30% then `accuracy_level` will be "Worst"

Here is my code:

```
actuals=seq(0,10,0.1)
forecast=seq(10,0,-0.1)
data1=data.frame(actuals,forecast)
data1$diff=data1$actuals-data1$forecast
data1$accuracy_percentage=(data1$diff/data1$actuals)*100
if((data1$accuracy_percentage < 10)&(data1$accuracy_percentage > -10),data1$accuracy_level="good",)
```

Comment: You can use `ifelse` instead of `if/else` or better may be to use `cut` and specify the `labels`

Comment: the first row of your df has an `inf` value. `0.0
10.0
-10.0
-Inf`

Comment: Best practices are to use white space so you and others can read your code and you don't accidentally do `x<-1` when trying to test `x < -1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data1$accuracy_level <- cut(abs(data1$accuracy_percentage), c(0, 10, 30, Inf), c("Good", "Bad", "Worst"), include.lowest=T)
#    actuals forecast diff accuracy_percentage accuracy_level
# 19     1.8      8.2 -6.4          -355.55556          Worst
# 71     7.0      3.0  4.0            57.14286          Worst
# 57     5.6      4.4  1.2            21.42857            Bad
# 17     1.6      8.4 -6.8          -425.00000          Worst
# 92     9.1      0.9  8.2            90.10989          Worst
# 91     9.0      1.0  8.0            88.88889          Worst
# 13     1.2      8.8 -7.6          -633.33333          Worst
# 79     7.8      2.2  5.6            71.79487          Worst
# 44     4.3      5.7 -1.4           -32.55814          Worst
# 51     5.0      5.0  0.0             0.00000           Good
```

Using `cut` will give you a boost in speed and scalability. We find the intervals of the absolute values, `abs`, of the accuracy percentages based on the cut points `c(0, 10, 30, Inf)`. And supply labels for the groups. We also add the argument `include.lowest=TRUE` for `0.000` cases which fall on the lower limit of our cut points.

Nested `ifelse` statements are used because they are easy to understand when read out. But if you had to nest 10 different conditions, it could easily get out of control.

As a note, if we did not require new label names, we could have used the related function `findInterval` which would essentially do the same thing with the difference of assigning integer values as output (i.e. `1 2 3 4..`).

Answer (score 2):

I used a compound `ifelse`

```
data1$accuracy_category <- ifelse(abs(data1$accuracy_percentage)<10, "Good",
                                  ifelse(abs(data1$accuracy_percentage)<30, "Bad", "Worst"))
```

yields

```
> head(data1)
  actuals forecast  diff accuracy_percentage accuracy_category
1     0.0     10.0 -10.0                -Inf             Worst
2     0.1      9.9  -9.8           -9800.000             Worst
3     0.2      9.8  -9.6           -4800.000             Worst
4     0.3      9.7  -9.4           -3133.333             Worst
5     0.4      9.6  -9.2           -2300.000             Worst
6     0.5      9.5  -9.0           -1800.000             Worst
```

and as pointed out by @pierre-lafortune, it is easier to read but less performant. In the spirit of [Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization) I ran some tests. With your initial set:

```
> system.time(data1$accuracy_category <- ifelse(abs(data1$accuracy_percentage)<10, "Good",
+ ifelse(abs(data1$accuracy_percentage)<30, "Bad", "Worst")))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> system.time(data1$accuracy_level <- cut(abs(data1$accuracy_percentage), c(0, 10, 30, Inf), c("Good", "Bad", "Worst"), include.lowest=T))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.000   0.001
```

but that isn't really telling. So let's crank it up :) With

```
actuals=seq(0,100000,0.1)
forecast=seq(100000,0,-0.1)
```

I got

```
> system.time(data1$accuracy_category <- ifelse(abs(data1$accuracy_percentage)<10, "Good",
+ ifelse(abs(data1$accuracy_percentage)<30, "Bad", "Worst")))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.776   0.060   0.840 
> system.time(data1$accuracy_level <- cut(abs(data1$accuracy_percentage), c(0, 10, 30, Inf), c("Good", "Bad", "Worst"), include.lowest=T))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.152   0.003   0.155
```

which does show that the `cut` will be much more performant as you scale up. All of that said, the `cut` is more elegant if not less readable, and I upvoted his answer :) ymmv.